# WPF AppDomain UnhandledException handler timeout

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

When an `AppDomain` has an unhandled exception, you can handle the `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` event.

However, you cannot prevent the `AppDomain` from shutting down. You can't just block the thread. Eventually the AppDomain will shut it down.

In ASP.NET, if you have objects registered (`IRegisteredObject`), the `AppDomain` will give your code 30 seconds to run.

Does anyone know what the timeout is for a standard WPF application?

Comment: I'm running an experiment and it seems like there's no timeout! Can I really run an infinite loop here?

Comment: A WPF app uses a different CLR host, its timeout for an unload is indeed INFINITE.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to set timeout for DispatcherUnhandledException handler

But, is the application terminating with a **Environment.Exit** or **Application.Exit** where there's an unhandled exception?

Quoting: http://www.dev102.com/2008/06/24/how-do-you-exit-your-net-application/

> **Environment.Exit** - From MSDN: Terminates this process and gives the
> underlying operating system the specified exit code. This is the code
> to call when you are using console application.
>
> **Application.Exit** -
> From MSDN: Informs all message pumps that they must terminate, and
> then closes all application windows after the messages have been
> processed. This is the code to use if you are have called
> Application.Run (WinForms applications), this method stops all running
> message loops on all threads and closes all windows of the
> application. There are some more issues about this method, read about
> it in the MSDN page.

For WPF, if an unhandled exception will crash the app with an **Environment.Exit** (as supposed to Application.Exit) - I suspect application don't exit until all threads are done. If so, then you may try do what you need to do via a thread in DispatcherUnhandledException handler.

Can you let me know if this is the behavior as well? I am curious. We never had problem with this as on WPF DispatcherUnhandledException handler we only do simple logging to disk